# Unknown Mass Spring Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

A student conducts an experiment to measure the motion of two unknown masses (A and B) along a smooth table. A constant force of 1 N was applied by means of a string connected by a falling weight.

A motion sensor recorded the position (measured from the start line) of each mass at regular time intervals as they slid along the table. The results displayed by the data logger are tabulated:

[image]

What would be the best way of describing the motion of both masses? Do you use acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_A$ and $m_A$ be their masses. By Newton's second law $$F=ma$$ where $a$ is the acceleration at any instant of time $t$ and $F$ is the amount of Force applied..
Since the Force experienced by $A$ and $B$ is constant the acceleration suffered by $A$ and $B$ is also constant so we can use the kinemetics relation:
$$s(t)=ut+\dfrac12at^2,\tag{1}$$
where $s$ is the distance moved in time $t$, $u$ is the initial velocity. We know that in your specific problem initial velocities are $0$. So their motion is best described by $1$ which further reduces to:
$$\begin{align} s(t)=\dfrac12at^2\\ v(t)=\dfrac{ds}{dt}=at\end{align}$$
$v$ is the velocity at time $t$. You can even find masses of $A$ and $B$ from the the given data, using equation $1$.

Comment: So how does this relate? How can you explain the motion of both masses?

Comment: @user34039 What do you mean by "_motion_"?

Comment: Their acceleration with respect to time.

Comment: @user34039 Have you read Newton's Laws?